# How to change the default message of the required field in the popover of form-control in bootstrap-vue?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I tried to disable or edit the invalid Pop over messages using a traditional Bootstrap method. But it doesn't work like that.

```
<b-form-input class="form-control" type="email"  required="" placeholder="username"
 oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please Enter valid email')"
 oninput="setCustomValidity('')"></b-form-input>
```

Answer (score 0):

But answer as follows.

**To disable popover messages**

```
<b-form-input id="email" v-model="form.email" type="email" :state="null" 
         placeholder="Enter email"></b-form-input>
```

To add custom messages, you should change a property **:state** as true or false and add label to make sure what is error.